# Can't access window object from within chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that will do something if it detects a specific object on the window object. For example in content.js I have

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
console.log(el[0].ownerDocument.defaultView.someObj);
```

This logs undefined. If I run the same code within the browser console. I will see that `someObj` exist. I get the correct element with

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
```

but it doesn't seem like I can get the correct window object. Any ideas?

my manifest looks like

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Ext",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/logo.svg"
  }
}
```

Comment: JS of an extension does not run in the same "context" as the main web view. It's does not act like an iFrame. To access the current loaded web page dom you need to use a content script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Note that `el[0].ownerDocument.defaultView.someObj` is an _extremely_ contrived way of saying `window.someObj`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Nope, that's already from a content script. You need to inject code into the page itself to access it.